# ajax request doesn't go through in axios

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, axios

So I'm using axios to be able to access Cloudinary API and upload photos. Then I want to be able to do an AJAX request that communicates with my own API to store the url for the photo I just uploaded. Here's my code:

```
$("#file-upload").change(function (event) {
        file = event.target.files[0];

$("#add-article").click(function () {
        formData.append('file', file);
        formData.append('upload_preset', CLOUDINARY_UPLOAD_PRESET);

        axios({
            url: CLOUDINARY_URL,
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            },
            data: formData
        }).then(function (res) {
            console.log(res);
            fileSource = res.data.secure_url;

            $.ajax({
                url: 'https://127.0.0.1:5000/api/admin/add_news',
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                data: JSON.stringify({
                    'title': newsTitle,
                    'imgSrc': fileSource
                }),
                method: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                crossDomain: true,
                success: function (res) {
                    alert(res.message);
                    location.reload();
                },
                error: function () {
                    console.log('error')
                },
                complete: function (jqXHR) {
                    if (jqXHR.status == '401') {
                        console.log(jqXHR.status)
                    }
                }
            });
        }).catch(function (err) {
            console.log(err);
        });

    });
```

I put all of this inside a document.ready function. It returns an error like this:[image]

I read about jQuery and JavaScript being compatible together, so what am I missing here?

Comment: If OPTIONS request failing then API is not CORS enabled

Comment: Not sure why you need to use both axios and $.ajax. They both do same thing but using both would not cause problems... it's all javascript

Comment: @charlietfl my API is already CORS enabled, using Flask btw. I was following a tutorial in cloudinary where he used axios. Tried converting it to and ajax request but ended up getting an illegal declaration error

Comment: Something wrong in back end if OPTIONS fails

Comment: @charlietfl noted. I'll try seeing whats wrong with it